# How can I filter-out rows based on values in preceding and following rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to filter out the data within a range in the MS SQL query. In this case "Test2" is my starting point and "Test4" is my ending point. I want to filter out "Test1" as long it is between "Test2" and "Test4" rows. If it's outside then I want to keep it. And also I want to keep "Test3" row.

Actual Result:

| DateTime | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-09 00:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 01:00 | Test2 |
| 2022-09-09 02:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 03:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 04:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-09 05:00 | Test4 |

Expected Result:

| DateTime | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-09 00:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 01:00 | Test2 |
| 2022-09-09 04:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-09 05:00 | Test4 |

2nd example

Actual Result:

| DateTime | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-08 11:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-08 12:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 01:00 | Test2 |
| 2022-09-09 02:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 03:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 04:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-09 05:00 | Test4 |

Expected Result:

| DateTime | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-08 11:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-08 12:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 01:00 | Test2 |
| 2022-09-09 04:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-09 05:00 | Test4 |

3rd example

Actual Result:

| DateTime | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-08 11:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-08 12:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 01:00 | Test2 |
| 2022-09-09 02:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 03:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 04:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-09 05:00 | Test4 |
| 2022-09-09 06:00 | Test1 |

Expected Result:

| DateTime | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-08 11:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-08 12:00 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 01:00 | Test2 |
| 2022-09-09 04:00 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-09 05:00 | Test4 |
| 2022-09-09 06:00 | Test1 |

Any help wil be appreciated.

SOLVED:

I managed to solve the problem thanks to the query provided by @Ahmed. Thanks to everyone that took the time to solve this.

Thank you!

Comment: I assume rows are always sorted by the `DateTime` column?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Dai yes, the rows are sorted by DateTime. And I'm using SQL Server 2019 (15.0.2000.5)

Comment: Can you give another example that shows what happens when you have multiple `'Test3'`  rows?

Comment: @Dai, I just edit the post and added another example

Comment: By "Actual result" do you really mean "Given this input data..."?

Comment: The problem is called gaps-and-island - a search on that should provide you the info you need.

Comment: I took a stab at this by messing around with `LAG` and `LEAD` and I was able to come to a solution for your first example, but not your second example. (Also, what should happen if two rows share the same `DateTime` value? And what if there's a single `Test1` row which only appears after `Test4`?)

Comment: @Dai Thank you! And for your first question, I dont think that will happen in my case but in that case could I use rowcount instead of datetime to determine whether or not 'Test1' is between 'Test2' and 'Test4'? For your second question, that one in particular I dont want it to filter out because it's outside.

Comment: Define "between"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT D.[DateTime], D.Message, SUM(D.F) OVER (ORDER BY [DateTime]) FLAG
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *,CASE WHEN Message ='Test2' OR Message='Test4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS F
    FROM table_name
  ) D
)
SELECT [DateTime], Message FROM CTE T 
WHERE(
        NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE D WHERE D.MESSAGE='Test2' AND D.FLAG=T.FLAG)
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE D WHERE D.MESSAGE='Test4' AND D.FLAG=T.FLAG+1)
        AND T.MESSAGE='Test1'
     ) 
     OR T.MESSAGE <> 'Test1'
     OR T.FLAG = 0
```

This query will filter out all 'Test1' values between 'Test2' and 'Test4', but not between 'Test4' and 'Test2' and that's according to your requirement; *"'Test2' is my starting point and 'Test4' is my ending point".*

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fod2e1bs).

Comment: This one is pretty close. I was able to to put it to work, but I missed one important point. When 'Test1' is outside the 'Test2' and 'Test4' (before or after) I don't want to wait for the next 'Test2' or 'Test4' to show 'Test1'. I want it to be flexible in case after 'Test4' (endpoint) I can still show the 'Test1' without waiting for the next 'Test2' (or viceversa). Thank you for your time.

Comment: I couldn't get you, can you explain this with a sample data

Comment: I edited the post to include a 3rd example, please refer to that one. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, the query covers all the data samples you provided, check this demos: [1st example](https://dbfiddle.uk/RmPkMb9m), [2nd example](https://dbfiddle.uk/3GkgWuqF), [3rd example](https://dbfiddle.uk/6fuIy1Rz)

Comment: I'm not sure about what you meant by "I don't want to wait for the next 'Test2' or 'Test4' ", but sql queries fetches the data row by row according to the specified order without waiting for any other row.

Comment: I managed to fit your code to my needs and now its working!! Thank you so much. I will mark the post as solved and give you credit. Thank you

Comment: Happy for you :), good luck

Answer (score 1):

I tried this query I can able to execute it:,

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        datetime,
        message
    FROM
        mytable
    WHERE
        datetime >= ( SELECT TOP 1 datetime d1 FROM mytable WHERE message = 'Test2' ) 
        AND
        datetime <= ( SELECT TOP 1 datetime d2 FROM mytable WHERE message = 'Test4' )
        AND
        message = 'Test1'
)
SELECT
    mt.datetime,
    mt.message
FROM
    mytable mt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cte ON
        mt.datetime = cte.datetime
        AND
        mt.message = cte.message
WHERE
    cte.datetime IS NULL
    AND
    cte.message IS NULL
```

[image: Screenshot of query and results]

(I am new to stack overflow; I would like to receive feedback if any errors in the code or if it isn't the right way).

Comment: Nice answer - it does seem to work for both cases - though you should add `ORDER BY` to the two `SELECT TOP 1...` subqueries otherwise you'll get meaningless results (as using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` results in undefined row ordering).

Comment: Yes, I did not think that way!! ORDER BY is very important to get the proper results.Thank you so much for correcting it. It was helpful  - @Dai

Answer (score 0):

```
select  DateTime
       ,last_group as Message
from    (
        select *
               ,case when Message = 'Test1' and start_end = 1 then null else Message end as last_group 
        from   (
                select * 
                       ,count(case when Message = 'Test2' then 1 when Message = 'Test4' then 1 end) over(order by DateTime) as start_end
                from t
               ) t
         ) t
where    last_group is not null
```

| DateTime | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-09 00:00:00.000 | Test1 |
| 2022-09-09 01:00:00.000 | Test2 |
| 2022-09-09 04:00:00.000 | Test3 |
| 2022-09-09 05:00:00.000 | Test4 |
| 2022-09-09 06:00:00.000 | Test1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V-hDjmOe?hide=16)